# Можно ли использовать несколько классов правил UrlManager?

Tags: yii2

есть два класса правила `UrlManager` первый:

```
<?php
namespace frontend\components;
class FilmUrlRule extends Object implements UrlRuleInterface
{

    public function createUrl($manager, $route, $params)
    {
        if ($route === 'film/category/onefilm') {
            if (isset($params['id'])) {
                return 'film/'.$params['id'].'/';
            }
        }elseif($route === 'film/category/list'){
            if(isset($params['slug'])&&isset($params['page'])&&isset($params['per-page'])){
                return 'film/'.$params['slug'].'?page='.$params['page'].'&per-page='.$params['per-page'].'/';
            }
            elseif ($route === 'film/category/list'&&isset($params['slug'])) {
                return 'film/'.$params['slug'].'/';
        }
    }
        return false;  // данное правило не применимо
    }

    public function parseRequest($manager, $request)
    {
        $pathInfo = $request->getPathInfo();
        if (preg_match('%^(\w+)(/([\wʹ]*))?$%', $pathInfo, $matches)) {
            $exists = Category::find()->where(['slug_category' => $matches[3]])->exists();
            if ($exists) {
                return ['film/category/list', ['slug' => $matches[3]]];
            }
        } elseif (preg_match('%^(\w+)(/(\w+)([+-/:/;]*([\wʹ]*)*)*)%', $pathInfo, $matches)) {
            $path = $matches[2];
            $pattern = '/film+[+-]/';
            if (preg_match($pattern, $path)) {
                $exists = Film::find()->where(['slug_film' => str_replace('/','',$matches[2])])->exists();
                if ($exists) {
                    return ['film/category/onefilm',['id'=>str_replace('/','',$matches[2])]];
                }
            }else{
                $exists = Category::find()->where(['slug_category' => str_replace('/','',$matches[2])])->exists();
                if ($exists) {
                    return ['film/category/list', ['slug' => str_replace('/','',$matches[2])]];
                }

            }

        }elseif (preg_match('/film/\/', $pathInfo)){
            return ['film/category/list'];
        }else{
            return false;  // данное правило не применимо
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

отрабатывает следующие запросы:

```
 Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['/serial/category/oneserial','id'=>$model->slug_serial])
 Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['/serial/category/list', 'slug' => $sct->slug_category])
```

и такой класс:

```
public function createUrl($manager, $route, $params)
{
    /*var_dump($route);*/
    if ($route === 'serial/category/oneserial') {
        if (isset($params['id'])) {
            return 'serials/'.$params['id'].'/';
        }
    }elseif($route === 'serial/category/list'){
        if(isset($params['slug'])&&isset($params['page'])&&isset($params['per-page'])){
            return 'serials/'.$params['slug'].'?page='.$params['page'].'&per-page='.$params['per-page'].'/';
        }
        elseif ($route === 'serial/category/list'&&isset($params['slug'])) {
            return 'serials/'.$params['slug'].'/';
    }
}
    return false;  // данное правило не применимо
}

public function parseRequest($manager, $request)
{
    $pathInfo = $request->getPathInfo();
    if (preg_match('%^(\w+)(/([\wʹ]*))?$%', $pathInfo, $matches)) {
        $exists = Category::find()->where(['slug_category' => $matches[3]])->exists();
        if ($exists) {
            return ['serial/category/list', ['slug' => $matches[3]]];
        }
    } elseif (preg_match('%^(\w+)(/(\w+)([+-/:/;]*([\wʹ]*)*)*)%', $pathInfo, $matches)) {
        $path = $matches[2];
        $pattern = '/serial+[+-]/';
        if (preg_match($pattern, $path)) {
            $exists = Serial::find()->where(['slug_serial' => str_replace('/','',$matches[2])])->exists();
            if ($exists) {
                return ['serial/category/oneserial',['id'=>str_replace('/','',$matches[2])]];
            }
        }else{
            $exists = Category::find()->where(['slug_category' => str_replace('/','',$matches[2])])->exists();
            if ($exists) {
                return ['serial/category/list', ['slug' => str_replace('/','',$matches[2])]];
            }

        }

    }elseif (preg_match('/serials/\/', $pathInfo)){
        return ['serial/category/list'];
    }else{
        return false;  // данное правило не применимо
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

отрабатывает следующие запросы:

```
 Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['/film/category/oneserial','id'=>$model->slug_serial])
 Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['/film/category/list', 'slug' => $sct->slug_category])
```

подключил так

```
'rules' => [
            [
                    'class' => 'frontend\components\FilmUrlRule',
                ],
                [
                    'class' => 'frontend\components\SerialsUrlRule',
                ],
]
```

но теперь если это правило отрабатывает хорошо

```
  Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['/film/category/oneserial','id'=>$model->slug_serial])
     Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['/film/category/list', 'slug' => $sct->slug_category])
```

то правило:

```
Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['/serial/category/list', 'slug' => $sct->slug_category])
```

вызывает route    `'/film/category/list'`  почему так не подскажите

Comment: Вы слишком усложняете жизнь. С Вашими правилами отлично справится и стандартный `urlManager`. Зачем Вам два менеджера не понимаю тоже, почему не написать один свой с приватными методами `getSerialCategoryUrl` и `getFilmCategoryUrl` и разрулить их в дефолтном `createUrl`.